# Image preview in telerik mvc editor

Tags: jquery, telerik

I have customize the telerik editor shown in below image-:[image: The dom object showing the html of li which contain image]

So how can i display selected image in a  div (showing in black box in the right side). I also do some stuff to find the image source by using this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('li.k-state-selected').live("click", function () {
          var src = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
          alert(src);
     });
});
```

but unable to get the source of an image.
please guide me on this that how can i do this.
Thanks

Comment: are you getting `alert`? and if yes what's the value inside it??

Comment: I am not getting call on alert.

Comment: That means your event is not getting fired!!! can you paste the `html`? what version of `jquery` you are using?

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/editorfile.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
Editor.js file is the js file for telerik editor tools.

Comment: Why have you included `jquery` file twice? Either include this `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>` or this `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>`. If you include first one you can use `.live` method or if you include 2nd one check its version and if it is greater than `jquery 1.7` use `.on` instead of `.live`. But use only either of `js` one file

Comment: @ Guruprasad Rao!! yes you are absolutely right thanks alot

Comment: Anytime!!! Happy coding... :)